# Modifying an ArrayList within an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have three classes. The Player Class:

```
public class Player
{
private String playerName;
private int playerWorth;
private int playerSpent;
// A list of player prize objects.
private ArrayList<Prize> playerPrizeList;

public void Player()
{
     playerPrizeList = new ArrayList <Prize>();
     playerName = "";
     playerWorth = 0;
     playerSpent = 0;
}

public void playerDetails(String playerName, int playerWorth, int playerSpent)
{
    setPlayerName(playerName);
    setPlayerWorth(playerWorth);
    setPlayerSpent(playerSpent);
}

public void prize(String prizeName, int prizeWorth, int prizeCost)
{
    populatePrize(prizeName, prizeWorth, prizeCost);
}

private void populatePrize(String prizeName, int prizeWorth, int prizeCost)
{
    playerPrizeList.add(new Prize(prizeName, prizeWorth, prizeCost));
}
```

The other class is PlayerList class from within which I am trying to add a new player object to an arrayList which works but then I also have a prizeList Array of (Prize Objects) inside this Player class. Once I add the player to the ArrayList how do I retrieve that object and make changes to (my last block of code). I hope I explained that properly.

```
public class PlayerList
{
private ArrayList<Player> playerAList; 

public PlayerList() 
{
    playerAList = new ArrayList<Player>();
}

public ArrayList<Player> addPlayer(String playerName, int playerWorth, int playerSpent)
{
    Player newPlayer = new Player();
    newPlayer.setPlayerName(playerName);
    newPlayer.setPlayerWorth(playerWorth);
    newPlayer.setPlayerSpent(playerSpent);
    playerAList.add(newPlayer);
    return playerAList;
}

/**
 * @i is the index of ArrayList for Player Prizes
 */
public void setPlayerPrizeList(int i, String prizeName, int prizeWorth, int prizeCost)
{
    playerAList.get(i) =  currentPlayer;
    currentPlayer.populatePrize(prizeName, prizeWorth, prizeCost);
    playerAList.set(i, currentPlayer);
    return playerAList;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have with your current code?

Comment: the setPlayerPrizeList is not doing what it's supposed to which is get an object with index i from the playerAList then add a new object (Prize) to it with prizeName/prizeWorth/prizeCost

Comment: Does this line even compile? `playerAList.get(i) =  currentPlayer;` Well, have a look at my answer below.

Comment: Why does a void method return an array list?

Comment: @BenKnoble good pickup sir. I have removed void and is now working like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your approach looks good.

There are a few issues in your code however:

1. You cannot assign values to a method call.

   ```
   playerAList.get(i) =  currentPlayer;
   ```

   This should work, however:

   ```
   currentPlayer = playerAList.get(i);
   ```
2. Besides that, you do not need this line:

   ```
   playerAList.set(i, currentPlayer);
   ```

   The `Player` you are changing in this method stays in the list and is "updated automatically", since all the changes are executed on the same memory block, the one your `Player` has been created in. Both your `playerAList` and the `currentPlayer` hold a reference to this memory block.
3. One more thing is wrong. You can't `return` anything from a method with return type `void`:

   ```
   return playerAList;
   ```

---

**All in all**, your method `setPlayerPrizeList()` should look like this:

```
public void setPlayerPrizeList(int i, String prizeName, int prizeWorth, int prizeCost) {
    currentPlayer = playerAList.get(i);
    currentPlayer.populatePrize(prizeName, prizeWorth, prizeCost);
}
```

Comment: very good answer @TimoSta . That compiled but now giving me null pointer exception error. Looks like i am not instantiating my ArrayList playerPrizeList. I guess before i populatePrize  i need to somehow do that right